# Is a Monk attack considered a finesse weapon attack?

Tags: dnd-5e, monk, rogue, sneak-attack, unarmed-combat

Since the Monk Martial Arts feature grants the ability to choose either Str or Dex as the modifier would the unarmed and flurry of blows be considered as finesse? the mechanics are essentially the same. This question is primarily for the purpose of figuring out if the Rogue Sneak Attack will work with a Monk Unarmed strike and Flurry of blows.